# Structured, No Heap FizzBuzz

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

Here was my first, simple C fizzbuzz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  for (int n = 1; n <= 100; ++n) {
    if (n % 3 == 0) printf("%s", "fizz");
    if (n % 5 == 0) printf("%s", "buzz");
    if ((n % 3 != 0) && (n % 5 != 0)) printf("%d", n);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I was messing around, trying to separate the transformation logic from the looping logic. As a whole, I don't think that my second `Buffer`-based solution is necessarily "better" *as a FizzBuzz solution*, but I did like the way that I dealt with a limited-purpose character buffer.

Thoughts on the second solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BUFF_SZ 9

typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef int i32;

/// A string buffer with a notion of its own size.
typedef struct Buffer {
  char *s;
  u32 sz;
  char *ins_ptr;
} Buffer;

/// Returns the content of the buffer.
const char *Buffer_content(Buffer *);

/// Clears contents of the buffer.
void Buffer_clear(Buffer *);

/// Appends a string S to the end of the buffer.
void Buffer_append_str(Buffer *, char *);

/// Appends the string representation of an integer to the end of the buffer.
void Buffer_append_i32(Buffer *, i32);

/// Returns 1 if the buffer has space for a certain number of chars, else 0.
u32 Buffer_has_space(Buffer *, u32);


/* HIGH LEVEL CODE */


/// Writes a number's fizzbuzz transformation into a Buffer.
void write_fizzbuzz_transformation(i32 n, Buffer *buff) {
  Buffer_clear(buff);
  if (n % 3 == 0) Buffer_append_str(buff, "fizz");
  if (n % 5 == 0) Buffer_append_str(buff, "buzz");
  if (*Buffer_content(buff) == '\0') Buffer_append_i32(buff, n);
}

void main() {
  // setup the string buffer (stack allocated)
  char internal_buff[BUFF_SZ];
  Buffer buff;
  buff.s = internal_buff;
  buff.sz = BUFF_SZ;


  for (i32 i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
    write_fizzbuzz_transformation(i, &buff);
    printf("%d -> %s\n", i, Buffer_content(&buff));
  }
}


/* DETAILS -- IMPLEMENTATION CODE */


u32 Buffer_has_space(Buffer *buff, u32 requested_sz) {
  u32 available_sz = buff->sz - (buff->ins_ptr - buff->s) - 1;
  return (available_sz >= requested_sz);
}

void Buffer_append_str(Buffer *buff, char* s) {
  u32 needed_sz = strlen(s);
  assert(Buffer_has_space(buff, needed_sz));
  strcpy(buff->ins_ptr, s);
  buff->ins_ptr += needed_sz;
}

void Buffer_append_i32(Buffer *buff, i32 n) {
  i32 original = n;
  u32 needed_sz = 0;
  if (n < 1) ++needed_sz;
  while (n) {
    n /= 10;
    ++needed_sz;
  }
  assert(Buffer_has_space(buff, needed_sz));
  sprintf(buff->ins_ptr, "%d", original);
  buff->ins_ptr += needed_sz;
}

void Buffer_clear(Buffer *buff) {
  buff->ins_ptr = buff->s;
  *(buff->ins_ptr) = '\0';
}

const char *Buffer_content(Buffer *buff) {
  return buff->s;
}
```

Comment: Short comment: (as a fizzbuzz solution) it's insane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Misleading**

Why would You something like this:

```
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef int i32;
```

That's quite misleading. On 64bit machines it's probably not going to be 32 bit wide. Standard `uint32_t`, `int32_t` types would be the way to go, if You really need fixed sized integers. Also, typedefing primitive types like that just sucks and kills readability.

Also, You're using `unsigned int` for storing `size`. Why not just `size_t`?

**Readability**

Typedefing `structs` as well kills a bit of readability.

What's `char *s;`? Start? String? Digging through Your code doesn't make it clearer, especially when You have something like this:

```
void Buffer_clear(Buffer *buff) {
  buff->ins_ptr = buff->s;
  *(buff->ins_ptr) = '\0';
}
```

What does this mean: `if (*Buffer_content(buff) == '\0')`? Something like `if (Buffer_isEmpty(buff))` would be waaaaay clearer.

Why would You mix casing in function names? `void write_fizzbuzz_transformation()`, but `const char *Buffer_content()`, etc.

Also, decide how do You form Your function names. `noun_verb`, `verb_noun`, or whatever. Now it's... quite inconsistent. Again, `write_fizzbuzz_transformation()`, but `Buffer_*()`.

**Generic rant**

`assert()` is not intended to be used for production code. It's used only for debugging purposes and only when `NDEBUG` is defined. Why wouldn't You have proper logger for errors like... not enough space and... wrong input? In fact, You have no control of wrong inputs because none of those are sanitized properly. For example imagine user of Your buffer library does something stupid like `Buffer_clear(NULL)`, `Buffer_content(NULL)`, etc.

In production code You have potential buffer overrun here:

```
void Buffer_append_str(Buffer *buff, char* s) {
  u32 needed_sz = strlen(s);
  assert(Buffer_has_space(buff, needed_sz));
  strcpy(buff->ins_ptr, s);
  buff->ins_ptr += needed_sz;
}
```

As I said before, `assert()` is used only for debugging purposes. You should use `strncpy()` or check buffer size explicitly. Same applies to `void Buffer_append_i32(Buffer *buff, i32 n)`.

Also, it would be nice if You'd provide proper error codes or 0 on success on Your buffer operations.

**Functionality**

You could shorten the following and make it safer using `snprintf()`:

```
u32 needed_sz = 0;
if (n < 1) ++needed_sz;
while (n) {
  n /= 10;
  ++needed_sz;
}
assert(Buffer_has_space(buff, needed_sz));
sprintf(buff->ins_ptr, "%d", original);
```

You have `#define BUFF_SZ 9`, but accepting unsigned integers, which are... by Your typedefs --- 32 bit long. So, anything over 99 999 999 goes to abyss...

**Warnings**

```
./fizz.c:45:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
void main() {
     ^
```

Comment: Lotta great feedback, thanks! Whose responsibility is safety, though, caller or callee? As callee, I *could* catch the *special* case of `Buffer_clear(NULL)`, but I can't catch the general case of casting any other invalid value as a Buffer pointer. In other words, other than a null check, library callee can't guarantee that the passed pointer points to a valid Buffer (or can it)?

Comment: Nope, You can't. Usually, there is proper constructor and destructor provided, like `Buffer_create()`, `Buffer_destroy()` with idea that the library is going to deal only with Buffer handles created using those.  Or, in other other words, only valid Buffer is created using `Buffer_create()`, if You're messing things in other ways, You're on Your own.

Comment: Thanks. Did some more reading about *assert*. I think you meant "only when `NDEBUG` is *[not]* defined."

Comment: Concerning "You should use strncpy() or check buffer size explicitly.": Incorrect usage of `strncpy()` is rampant, so unless one provides an example or references proper usage, this advice is not constructive.

Comment: `sprintf(buff->ins_ptr, "%d", original);` without checking its result trades one form of error for another without overall code improvement.  Again not  truly constructive.

Comment: @chux checking the result is a must anyway. Also that's just brief points, not full blown code snippets to change. Later I'll try to get more into details.